# Browser font settings not honoured on SE sites

Tags: bug, fonts

Recently, it seems that Stack Exchange sites have stopped honouring my browser font settings.

I use Firefox 33.0.2 on Linux, and have always chosen to disable the "Allow pages to choose their own fonts" option. Up until the last couple of weeks, this has worked fine on Stack Exchange sites. My default font is set to "Sans Serif" (which I think resolves to "Deja Vu Sans"), and this is exactly what I got when viewing pages. Now, though, all pages are rendered with some kind of serif font, which I am unable to change.

If I go to other sites (e.g. wikipedia, bbc news, youtube, etc), and change the default font in the Firefox preferences, the page immediately shows the changes. It just seems to be the Stack Exchange sites which refuse to honour the new settings.

Can anyone explain what might have caused this change in behaviour? And is there anything I can do to get the old behaviour back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `font.default.x-unicode` now needs to be set in order for things to work properly on SE sites. Previously, I only needed to set `font.default.x-western` to get my preferred fonts.